# Is there a website like appspot for hosting perl script

Tags: perl

I know that there is a lot of free hosting but they seem bad and unsecured.Also good ones are
not free.Is there a free place to host perl script.In Node.Js there is no.de,for python and java there is appspot

Comment: You are correct, good ones are generally not free, and for a reason, they cost money to run.  Before this question can be effectively answered, a definition of 'good' and 'secured' is needed.  For instance, I believe that most developers would agree that linode is good, but you can make your instance as insecure as you want there.  Please clarify what your needs are.  If you are just trying to test (common with free servers, where you aren't trying to make full-fledged apps) try Virtual Box or other VMs.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but there is http://www.ideone.com/ which is a pastebin except:

> Ideone is something more than a
>   pastebin; it's an online compiler and
>   debugging tool which allows to compile
>   and run code online in more than 40
>   programming languages.

... including Perl.